# How to avoid Jaxb marshaller to be taken from javaee.jar of weblogic?

Tags: java, jaxb, classpath, marshalling

I need a custom prefix in namespace,I have used below code

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
        return "tf";
    }
});
```

But, it still giving me `propertexception`, after analysis i found out that the marshaller and jaxbcontent i was using are from javaee.jar of weblogic.But, I want it from java 1.6.

I have tried to specify it in my weblogic startup. But no use...!!
What am i missing..!!
How to mention java to take it from it's own rt.jar rather than javaee.jar of weblogic??

Comment: What exception are you getting an which version of WebLogic are you using?

Comment: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: com.db.tf.interfaces.util.MessageParserComponent$1@ac08ec

Comment: I'm using Java 1.6 and weblogic 10.3

Comment: When i try to import and use                            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller or               javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext                                         they were taken from javee.jar of weblogic classpath. I want it to take it from tr.jar of jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

> At runtime the jaxbcontext created was from glassfish jar of weblogic.
>
> When i have avoided my application to access it, it took the regular rt.jar of java jdk and the prefix got generated successfully.

Comment: hi Can you please provide the detail solution of resolving this? please

Comment: @iHappyk  changed my weblogic classpath jars order, which changed the class loder preferences

Comment: @iHappyk  I have changed my **weblogic classpath jars order**. This changed the class loader preferences, ie., made `rt.jar` jaxbcontext  class available first than the glassfish jar of weblogic.

Comment: thank you let me change in mine as well and see if it works